# Flckr image exif data can't pass to a dictonary in python

Tags: python, api, flickr

I was trying to extract the EXIF data of images using the flickr API. My code has shown below:
`photos=flickr.photos.search(text=["shark"],has_geo=1,extras='geo')`

then I was trying to store few Exif data from each image into dictionary as,

```
data=[]
for photo in photos["photos"]["photo"]:
data.append({"id":photo["id"],"owner":photo["owner"],"title":photo["title"]
```

however when I see,
  `len(data)`
it was printed out as 250, however, when I check `len(photos)` I have found that it contained 750 photos. I couldn't understand why other 500 photos aren't displaying in.
I also noticed that calling `photos` result following dictonary:

```
{'photos': {'page': 1,
  'pages': 3,
  'perpage': 250,
  'photo': [{'accuracy': '16',
    'context': 0,
    'farm': 5,
    'geo_is_contact
```

any help would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: the length of `photos["photos"]` might not be equal to the length of `photos["photos"]["photo"]` which what you are iterating over.

Comment: Why are you comparing the length of ``data`` to ``photos``? You should check the length of ``photos["photos"]["photo"]`` instead.